# Apache htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I am having some issues with my htacces file trying to do some re-write conditions.
What I am trying to do is:

There are multiple domains pointed to this web folder.
If the domain is anything but example.com I want it to rewrite to example.com
UNLESS - the path is /path

**Everything is working now except when you go to www.otherexample.com/path**

It is hitting the last rule and changing the url to *http://dev.otherexample.com/index.php?qs-rewrite=path* and causes a redirect loop.

Here's the entire htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        !^/path [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$                  http://dev.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule .                     %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$                  index.php?qs-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        !^/path [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}       !qs-rewrite=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^                     http://dev.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}        ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule .                     /%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteRule ^                     /index.php?qs-rewrite=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried that and same thing, I am adding the entire htaccess to the question.

Comment: What URL did you use for testing this rule?

Comment: So, dev.examplstest1.com/path1 should not get re-written but with this it comes out as http://dev.example.com/?qs-rewrite=path1

Comment: Ok so you want to strip out query string also, try edited code now.

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain a little better maybe. So what I expect if you were to try to go to notexample.com/path1 the site should NOT rewrite to example.com it should only rewrite to example.com if the "/path1" text is missing and the site name is not example.com

Comment: Yes I understand that and if you place above rules on top of your other rules this is what it exactly does.

Comment: I think the rule you gave me would work if used without this part:

    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qs-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

This part seems to be changing it back?

Comment: If you post your latest .htaccess again and clearly tell me which rule isn't working I can sure suggest you a fix.

Comment: Ok, Big Thanks! for all your help. The last re-write rule has to be like this  `RewriteRule ^.*$                /index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]`  without the leading slash it tries to go to c: file directory. If you can update your answer to include this I will choose it as my answer. Thanks Again

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ index.php?qs-rewrite=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]` has same effect and when you have `QSA` you don't need `&%{QUERY_STRING}`